# Classes become main classes and have error parsing files

Tags: android, netbeans

I got netbeans to be able to deal with android. I created my classes with the first page being my main classes. As I created my other classes, the last one I worked on would suddenly become a main class and have a problem parsing the file. I tried running it to see if it worked the way it was supposed to but now they are all main classes and having problem parsing file.This is my `run.xml` file. it shows there is something wrong here.

[image]

Comment: please add the error code here for reference, also

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you did but there are no main classes in Android projects. What you have is the main activity which is defined in manifest.

According to your output the actual problem is that **android.app package is missing**. This is most likely because of the project dependencies are missing. Maybe you should look into the project structure and check what is going wrong.

BTW if you want to deal with android, Android Studio will be a much better choice.

Comment: I tried android studio. It started searching for a android manifest that i never had and i couldn't make the manifest that it was looking for. It suddenly lost my jdk and i have nothing to use as a home for it.  I couldn't try testing it cause something also messed up there. I am working on this at school as a project for my advanced programming class. I don't have access to my command prompt as well as a number of other things on my computer.